# The if else works exactly opposite of what I wanted

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

The following code is part of controller, which toggles "like" status of a post.

It works like this:

1. First it looks for any likes on the post by the user.
2. If it does not exist, "save" like status.
3. If it exists, "delete" the existing like status.

Here is the code is:

```
// api/posts
exports.postLikes = function(req,res){
    var like = new Like({
        postId: req.params.postId,
        user: req.user._id
    });
    Like.find()
    .and([
        {user:req.user._id},
        {postId:req.params.postId}
    ]) // check for existing likes
    .exec(function(err, result){
        if(!result){ // if there is no result
            like.save(function(err){
                if(err){res.send(err);}
                Post.findById(req.params.postId, function(err,post){
                    if(err) return res.send(err);
                    post.likeId.push(like);
                    post.save(function(err){
                        if(err) return res.send(err);
                        res.json({status:'done'})
                    });
                });
            });
        }else{ //if there is result
            res.json({status:'deleted'}) // just says deleted for now
        };
    });
};
```

However, It returns `{status:'deleted'}` when there is no result and adds additional likes when there is already a result.

result returns like stored in MongoDB

```
{ _id: 555f4ee2f0ea4f8004690ba5,
  postId: 555e649b3e5e24f0200f0f16,
  user: 555e1c9fd5ec350421ec7cfa,
  __v: 0,
  created: Sat May 23 2015 00:44:34 GMT+0900}
```

if it does not exists, it returns

```
[]
```

I changed my code to work simpler for testing purpose

```
if(result != null){
    res.send(result + "deleted")
}else{
    res.send(result + "added")
};
```

now both says result + 'deleted'

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated.  If all this is doing is toggling the like status of a post, all you should need is one `if` `then` `else`.

Comment: Does `result` evaluate to zero if it is not given? A string such as "no results found", for example, does *not*.

Comment: What is the value of `result` in both cases?

Comment: An empty array is [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: @KeonKim `![]` will actually return false, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/um35vpvq/).

Comment: @PM77-1: yeah those were the terms I was looking for: 'truthy' and 'falsy'. Best behavior describing terminology *ever*.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - That's backwards, if it's `false` you'll get `!result`. Use the evaluation before negation, you should see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/um35vpvq/1/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks guys i got whats wrong, I thought empty array would return false.

Comment: @KeonKim - It's a little strange-looking that it returns an object or, if no result, an empty array?

Comment: @JaredFarrish That what I think, too... I will have to study more on that. I'll let you know what I find later

Comment: @JaredFarrish Sorry if it's not clear, the program is meant to alert which value is true. So it would alert `!result` if that value `!result` was true and `result` otherwise. They where placeholders more than anything.

Comment: Mixing return types is bad practice (except for null or undefined which are easy to handle). It shouldn't return either an array or object. It should either return an object or null OR it should return an array of objects or an empty array (in other words it should return an array). If the return value is always an array then it's easy to check `return.length` to see if it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (with my emphasis):

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except
>   for **false**, **0**, **""**, **null**, **undefined**, and **NaN**).

An empty array (`[]`) is not on the above list, so it's **truthy**.

You may want to return `null` instead.